# Manejo Archivos pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x

Un saludo a todos(as) necesito hacer un programa en python que permita ver un archivo .pdf que se entrega en una memoria, pero que a su vez no permita que se copie, la verdad estoy perdido sobre la librería más apropiada para hacer esto.
No se exactamente por donde empezar y no se si sea la forma correcta de plantear una inquietud si algo falta estoy dispuesto a corregirlo para que por favor me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Falta información, mira aquí [Cómo crear archivos PDF en Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252726/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python) (esta en inglés pero puedes traducirlo fácilmente), con esto te puede hacer una ida.

Comment: Gracias lo voy a mirar y le comento, la idea es que el archivo ya está sino que se entrega en una memoria y no queremos que se copie, y pensé en hacer algo en python para poder digamos ocultarlo, protegerlo, limitar las opciones de impresión, si manipularlo y pasarlo a una base de datos y luego mostrarlo no se es algo así lo que necesito. He tratado de mirar y modificar programas que he encontrado, pero me siento muy perdido. Asi que gracias voy a leer la información.

Comment: Hola buenos días he estado trabajando en el programa que necesito hacer, pero me sigue sacando error este es el código:

Comment: Hola buenos días he estado trabajando en el programa que necesito hacer, saca este error  :PdfReadWarning: PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode. It may not be read correctly. [pdf.py:1079],Exception in Tkinter callback,Traceback (most recent call last):
  "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream),  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1689, in read,  stream.seek(-1, 2)
io.UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero end-relative seeks

Comment: from tkinter import *
import PyPDF2

def libro():
    print("paso por aqui")
    pdf_file = open('C:\Python34\imagenes\libro.pdf')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = page.extractText()
    print(paginaPDF.extractText())


def close_window():
    window.destroy()
    exit()

Button(window, text="Exit", width=12, command=close_window) .grid(row=17, column=0, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()

Comment: Mire esto: [PdfReadWarning: PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32275435/8933039) y además [Stream has ended unexpectedly error on certain PDF files](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/99)

Comment: Gracias ya estoy mirando lo que me dijo, de verdad muchas gracias si logro solucionarlo le cuento, buen día.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, gracias a los que me guiaron para poder abrir un archivo .pdf con python, finalmente de tanto buscar encontre una instrucción que lo abre es la siguiente: webbrowser.open_new(nombre) cargando la rura completa y el nombre del archivo en la variable nombre abrio el .pdf utilizando el acrobat reader, quise compartir con ustedes la forma como logre solucionar el problema que tenia. Espero sea de utilidad y nuevamente gracias a todos.